# How should i set variables decided in a while loop

Tags: while-loop

I am a new programmer making a game at the moment but am having difficulty deciding how to allow people to select a role, each role has different values for health damage etc but i wanted it in a while loop so  if it was incorrectly typed it will just re ask the question, any better ways to do it so I am able to access the variables everywhere in my code?

```
int damage;
int health;
int speed;
int x = 0;
while(x == 0) {
    String role;
    System.out.println("Would you like to select a knight, wizard, or rogue? If you would like more information on class tpye: info(class) with no spaces.");
    role = user_input.next();
    if (role.equalsIgnoreCase("infoknight")) {
        System.out.println("You start with a normal sword. The knight has 15 health, 10 damage, and 5 speed");
    }else if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("infowizard")){
        System.out.println("You start with a normal wand. The wizard has 10 health 10 damage and 10 speed and is the most balanced class to start with");
    }else if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("inforogue")) {
        System.out.println("You start with a normal dagger. The rogue has 10 health, 5 damge, and 15 speed and is the most difficult class to start with\n");
    }else if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("knight")) {
        System.out.println("You selected a knight!\nYou will start with a wooden sword.");
        damage = 10;
        health = 15;
        speed = 5;
        x = 1;
    }else if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("Wizard")) {
        System.out.println("You selected a wizard!\n You will start with a old wand.");
        damage = 10;
        health = 10;
        speed = 10;
        x = 1;
    }else if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("rogue")) {
        System.out.println("You selected a rogue!\nYou will start with a dull dagger");
        damage = 5;
        health = 10;
        speed = 15;
        x = 1;
    }else {
        System.out.println("Incorrectly typed please try again");
    }


}
```

Comment: "variable scope".  I'd suggest getting a beginner's book in your language (whatever c-like one you're coding in here) and read it.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to set yourself a project to learn coding, so please realize that this design has a ways to go.

You need, for Java or any other object-oriented language, to be thinking in terms of the objects, or entities, that your program operates on. In this case, you have an object (that is, a `class` of a Player), and you also have a number of connected attributes that should probably be grouped as a sub-object, or kept in a Collection of some sort (e.g., a map). The programming concept of `break` in a loop would also let you clean this up.